# How do I create a list of all combinations, given a population and subset? (nCr)

Tags: python, math, statistics

I am trying to get a List of Lists for all of the combinations with a given Population and a given SubSet.

For this example, say there's a population of 12, and a subset of 3. From the Combinations Formula (nCr) I know there should be 220 combinations. How do I get a list of all of the 220 possible combinations?

Example Result:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 etc.,
 etc.,
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all possible combinations of the 3 indices where you have ones, and build each output accordingly:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combs(n, r):
    for comb in combinations(range(n), r):
        yield [1 if i in comb else 0 for i in range(n)]
```

Sample run with your values:

```
c = list(combs(12, 3))
print(len(c))
# 220
```

We have the expected number of combinations, see the first ones:

```
print(c[:5])
# [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```